# jQuery .addClass and .fadeIn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So, I have these h1 elements that are links and I want to add a class to them and fade that class in once the element has been hovered over, and then onMouseOut have the class removed, whilst fading the class. But using the fade function does nothing for me. Seeing as it hides the element. Any ideas?

```
jQuery(".categories h1 a").hover(
function () {
    jQuery(this).fadeIn("slow").addClass("active");
},
function(){
    jQuery(this).fadeOut("slow").removeClass("active");
});
});
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:::**

```
jQuery("h1").hover(function() {
      jQuery(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"}, 800);
      },function() {
      jQuery(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 800);
      });
});
```

Comment: Clarity please, what do you want to fade in? Do you want the link to fade in one you hover over the h1? Your code will fade, if it worked, would only server to fade the link out, but then you won't be able to fade it in again.

Comment: No. I want to fade in the class added to the h1>a tag. and then fade out on mouse out

Comment: @AaronBrewer See >>http://jsfiddle.net/NLChW/4/ << using animate

Comment: @Vega: http://squaredcube.com/beta/ Not working.

Comment: @AaronBrewer You need to include jQuery UI library in your page. Try including `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your page and it should work.

Comment: @Vega: Ahh, that makes a lot more sense now... Thank you! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using jQuery UI [.addClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/) and [.removeClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/removeClass/).

```
$(function() {
    $(".categories h1 a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).addClass("active", 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop(true,true).removeClass("active", 100);
    });    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLChW/3/) (For some reason, it doesn't animate properly(fade) for the first time.. but then onwards it works fine)

**Edit:** Updated for completeness.

You can also use `.animate` to get the desired effect. See below,

```
$(function() {
    $(".categories h1 a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"
        }, 800);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        }, 800);
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLChW/4/)

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it. Check out my answer below, I feel it's cleaner. Is there a reason you're using stop functionality and addClass instead of toggle?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall Reason for .stop is to stop fade transition or else hovering over multiple links quickly is going to show multiple animation at the same time. Well you would be able to see it when you have longer duration (1000ms)

Comment: Interesting, Thanks for explaining! I shouldn't make assumptions about the users mouse speed haha.

Answer (score 8):

If you dont wanna use jquery UI because it will be an extra load, you can do the following :

(was useful to me when the 'hidden' bootstrap class is used in my app)

Fade In slowly while removing the class  :

```
$('.myClass').removeClass('hidden').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(10000)
```

Fade Out slowly, add the class and then fade back in:

```
$('.myClass').fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).addClass('hidden'); //or any other class
}).fadeIn(10000)
```

hope this will simplify someone's task!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the styles of the class to fade in. You should look into animate() for that:  http://api.jquery.com/animate/

fadeIn simply fades in the element.

Comment: Alright, I tried using this Animate function and can't seem to even make it work now... See updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can cross fade between classes, but you can use the `animate` function.  `animate` allows you to affect any css variable over a specified time.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I know that removes some styling from the css file, but again, I don't think jQuery will cross fade between classes.

Comment: Alright, I tried using this Animate function and can't seem to even make it work now... See updated question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the jQuery UI library loaded, you can set an extra param for the toggleClass function.

Set your opacity's via css.

```
h1 a {
  opacity:0.8;
}

h1 a.hovered {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

then

```
jQuery(".categories h1 a").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover', 1000);
}
```

The 1000 is the millisecond counter on the event. So the effect should fade to 1.0 opacity when hovered in a second and fade out in 1 second when not hovered.

Comment: Which is why I said "If you have the jQuery UI library loaded". ;}

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and here's the jsFiddle ([enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/KzZQU/)) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(".categories h1").hover(function () {
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({ "background-color": "#a7bf51"}, 800);
            jQuery(this).addClass("active");
            jQuery(this).find("a").fadeIn("slow");
        },
        function() {
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({ "background-color": "#FFFFFF"}, 800);
            jQuery(this).addClass("active");
            jQuery(this).find("a").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .categories h1 {
        background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 100px
    }
    .categories h1 a {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<div class="categories">
    <h1><a href="#">Item 1</a></h1>
    <h1><a href="#">Item 2</a></h1>
    <h1><a href="#">Item 3</a></h1>
</div>​
```