# How to make JQuery CSS color fade in then out?

Tags: jquery

So when someone fills out an area of a form then it this gets the id and turns green.  I would like the green to fade in then out.  For some reason it only fades in with this code.

```
var id = this.id  
$("#"+ id).css({border: '0 solid rgb(0, 255, 12)'}).animate({ borderWidth: 2}, "fast");
```

I did try this, from the suggestions, but still didn't get it to work:

```
$("#"+ id).css(function(){
    $(this).animate({         backgroundColor: "#000000"     }, "slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({         backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"     }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't fade colors, you'll need a plugin or to use CSS animation for that

Comment: check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439310/jquery-addclass-and-fadein

Comment: I was trying to do css animation, what am I missing?

Comment: Well, the question is at least missing the CSS you've tried ?

Comment: I have tried, and I also I tried the extra code I added above.  I did it with the background instead of the border for now to just see if it worked.

Comment: That's not CSS animations, that's jQuery animations, and again, jQuery doesn't animate colors without a plugin or jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with CSS animation, just change `focus` to `blur` if you want to perform some actions after the field is filled in.

```js
$("input").on("focus", function() {
  $(this).addClass("correct");
});
```

```css
input {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  outline: 0;
  padding: .5em;
}

.correct {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: fade;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% { border-color: #ccc; }
  50% { border-color: rgb(0, 255, 12); }
  100% { border-color: #ccc; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Comment: I also added this to make it reusable :    $("#"+ id).addClass("correct");
  setTimeout( function(){ $("#"+ id).removeClass("correct"); }, 4000 );

Comment: since the `animation-duration: 3s` you can remove the class after 3 seconds instead of 4, so the animation will be immediately available