# How to add FadeIn & FadeOut for the below jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add FadeIn & FadeOut for the below jquery function?

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".header-transparent").addClass("dark-header");
    } else {

       $(".header-transparent").removeClass("dark-header");
    }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439310/jquery-addclass-and-fadein

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .addClass and .fadeIn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439310/jquery-addclass-and-fadein)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
       $(".header-transparent").fadeIn(5000).addClass("dark-header");
  } else {

      $(".header-transparent").fadeOut(5000).removeClass("dark-header");
   }
});
```

if you want a small delay before `addclass`, then use [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: Hi there, Actually the whole header got disappeared once scroll back to the top of the page. So kindly give me any solution, please.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @JohnsmithFN fadeIn will disappear the div by fading.. whatever, to hold this stage, add 5s time on fadein , try the code above now

Answer (score 0):

```js
This Piece of snippet will do-

$(window).scroll(function(){
            if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 50){
                $(".header-transparent").fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    $(this).addClass("dark-header")
                           .fadeIn('fast');
                });
            } else {
                $(".header-transparent").fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("dark-header")
                           .fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
        });
```